# JQtouch error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

I am using JQtouch to simulate sliding / swiping events for a mobile application and i am trying to simulate it first in google chrome browser.

But, when i load the page I get this error :

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'` in JQtouch.js.

The stack trace in console is like this :

`$.fn.tap jqtouch.js:1
addAnimation jqtouch.js:1
(anonymous function) jqtouch.js:1
c jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
p.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4`

I am not understanding what is causing this error . Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your plugin is outdated and uses jQuery methods that have been removed from jQuery (live).

Comment: So what you are saying is that, my version of the jquery.js , actually does not contain the method 'live'  ?

Comment: [`live()` was removed in jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: So , i have to update the version of jqtouch.js ?

Comment: If there is an update available, yes.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight definitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the latest version from https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch which supports jQuery v2 as live() was deprecated in v1.7 and got removed in v1.9

Comment: Thanks, perhaps, you can also look at this question that i posted :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956933/uncaught-typeerror-in-jqtouch

Comment: Checked out the question and answered!