# Uncaught TypeError in jQTouch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch, zepto

I am trying to use the swipe event in `jQtouch`. For that purpose, i have a code which uses latest `jQtouch.js` . But, when i try to initialize this, i get this error in my browser console :

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

The error is present here in this line :

```
 var jQT = new $.jQTouch({

});
```

However, if i do not use this line , then the `swipe` event does not work, since, `jQtouch` dose not get initialized.

I have no idea how to solve this . Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the plugin from here

https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/blob/eb1291bf336462d7c5aa2521838ecf797395442a/src/reference/jqtouch.js

and then you can initialize using

```
var jQT = new $.jQTouch({

});
```